# BSON value present in the document for a Mongoid has_and_belongs_to_many relationship, but reference isn't accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid, has-and-belongs-to-many

I've got a has_and_belongs_to relationship between two models in my Rails app (using Mongoid).  Relevant bit of model code:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :intro_users, class_name: 'Game', inverse_of: :intro_games, autosave: true

has_and_belongs_to_many :intro_games, class_name: 'Game', inverse_of: :intro_users, autosave: true
```

From the console, I can see that the relevant BSON is embedded in documents for both models, and I can access the relationship going one way:

```
irb(main):025:0> u = _
=> #<User _id: 52f6cb425365619a52010000, {...},  intro_game_ids: [BSON::ObjectId('535eeb6e53656107dc0c0000')]>
irb(main):026:0> u.intro_games
=> [#<Game _id: 535eeb6e53656107dc0c0000, {...}, intro_user_ids: [BSON::ObjectId('52f6cb425365619a52010000')]>]
```

But not the other way.  The value's in the document, but the reference comes back empty:

```
irb(main):022:0> g.reload
=> #<Game _id: 535eeb6e53656107dc0c0000, {...}, intro_user_ids: [BSON::ObjectId('52f6cb425365619a52010000')]>
irb(main):023:0> g.intro_users
=> []
```

Already restarted the console, so it's not a model refresh.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your 'Game' is referencing users with an improper classname.
Second line should have the referenced class of 'User' instead of 'Game' -- otherwise mongoid will be looking up a 'Game' with the id of a 'User'.

Not sure why mongoid doesn't throw an exception for this.

Comment: Good eye.  Yeah, that was it.  When I restarted the console with the correct class_name set, the references started behaving themselves in both directions (was surprised it even let me store objects of incorrect class).